# Javascript and CSS for Automatic Slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I would like to know how to make this slider to automatic slideshow.
This slider contains clickable bullets at the bottom and pre/next buttons on the slides but doesn't animate itself.

Would anyone please let me know how to make it automatic slideshow?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **setInterval()** function to make the slideshow automatically for the certain time interval.
Add the  setInterval() function in your example reference link after the below line:

> var slideIndex = 1;
>   showSlides(slideIndex);
>
> `setInterval(function(){ showSlides(++slideIndex); }, 1000);`

The slide will be changed every **1000 milli seconds**. If you need you can adjust the time as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what the click on the next button does: call `plusSlider` with a parameter `1`.

To do that every 2000ms your can use setInterval. On that w3schools tryit page put following code before the closing `</script>` then run it:

```
setInterval(plusSlides,2000,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is making use of a **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** function such as the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
  slideIndex++;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}, 3000);
```

The above function increases the current index, then triggers the `showSlides()` function, passing the index as a parameter. The `3000` denotes the speed at which the automation should occur, with the time specified in millseconds. Note that `setInterval()` should be used rather than `setTimeout()`, because `setInteravl()` fires **more than once**.

This gives the following result:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  slideIndex++;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}, 3000);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">
  
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

i have do some changes in the code , and create as a auto slider with custom card

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setInterval(function(){ showSlides(++slideIndex); }, 4000);
}
```

```css
  /* Slideshow container */
.slide-slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 60vh;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.slide-prev, .slide-next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.slider-product{
  max-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.slider-product:hover{
  border: 1px solid #006ba3;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.slide-next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.slide-prev:hover, .slide-next:hover {
  color: block;
}

/* Caption text */
.slide-text {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 8px; */
  top:0;
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;

  
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.slide-numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.slide-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .slide-dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .5} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .slide-prev, .slide-next,.slide-text {font-size: 11px}

}
```

```html
<div class="slide-slideshow-container">

<div class="slide-mySlides fade">
  <div class="slide-numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="slide-text">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="slider-product">
        <img src="xyz.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <h4 style="text-align: left; margin: 0.5em 0;">card no 1</h4>
        <p style="text-align: left; color: #1e1d1e;">Qui placeat nesciunt sit omnis voluptate et voluptatem unde et magni possimus eos autem tempore a pariatur autem sed labore autem!</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-mySlides fade">
  <div class="slide-numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="slide-text">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="slider-product">
        <img src="xyz.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <h4 style="text-align: left; margin: 0.5em 0;">card no 2</h4>
        <p style="text-align: left; color: #1e1d1e;">Qui placeat nesciunt sit omnis voluptate et voluptatem unde et magni possimus eos autem tempore a pariatur autem sed labore autem!</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-mySlides fade">
  <div class="slide-numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="slide-text">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="slider-product">
        <img src="xyz.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <h4 style="text-align: left; margin: 0.5em 0;">card no 3</h4>
        <p style="text-align: left; color: #1e1d1e;">Qui placeat nesciunt sit omnis voluptate et voluptatem unde et magni possimus eos autem tempore a pariatur autem sed labore autem!</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-mySlides fade">
  <div class="slide-numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="slide-text">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="slider-product">
        <img src="xyz.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <h4 style="text-align: left; margin: 0.5em 0;">card no 4</h4>
        <p style="text-align: left; color: #1e1d1e;">Qui placeat nesciunt sit omnis voluptate et voluptatem unde et magni possimus eos autem tempore a pariatur autem sed labore autem!</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-mySlides fade">
  <div class="slide-numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="slide-text">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="slider-product">
        <img src="xyz.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <h4 style="text-align: left; margin: 0.5em 0;">card no 5</h4>
        <p style="text-align: left; color: #1e1d1e;">Qui placeat nesciunt sit omnis voluptate et voluptatem unde et magni possimus eos autem tempore a pariatur autem sed labore autem!</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="slide-prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="slide-next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
```